# How to put a label on a vertical line above the end of the line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I did a graph with *ggplot*. My aim is to add labels at the top of the vertical lines I put in the graph. The problem is that these labels appear not above enough. They intersect the vertical line. Instead, I would like them not to touch the vertical lines.

For instance:

```
 date <- seq(2000, 2010, by = 1)
 value <- seq(1, 11, by=1)
 df <- data.frame(Date = date, Value = value) 

 ggplot(df, aes(x = df$Date)) + geom_line(aes(y = df$Value, colour = "Value"), size = 1) + theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "grey", size = 0.8)) + labs(y = "\n \n", x = "", colour = "") + theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", face = "plain", size = 12, colour = "black")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = df$Date[c(3)], linetype="dashed", colour = "black", size=1) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=df$Date[3], y= Inf, label = "Label"), colour = "black", vjust = 1, size = 5)
```

How can I push the label in a way that they don't intersect the dashed lines?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps inserting a `geom_segment` is what you are looking for:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, colour = "Value"), size = 1) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2005, y = 0, xend = 2005, yend = 9, colour = "segment"), data = df) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=df$Date[6], y= 10, label = "Label"), colour = "black", vjust = 1, size = 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This'll be hard with your current approach because `geom_vline` draws a line that goes on forever in both directions. You could push your text to the right or left in your call to `geom_text` though. If you really want to have the text right above the vertical line, I'd suggest using `annotate` to draw the line instead:

```r
library(ggplot2)

date <- seq(2000, 2010, by = 1)
value <- seq(1, 11, by=1)
df <- data.frame(Date = date, Value = value) 

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, colour = Value), size = 1) + 
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "grey", size = 0.8)) + 
  labs(y = "\n \n", x = "", colour = "") + 
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", face = "plain", size = 12, colour = "black")) +
  geom_text(aes(x=df$Date[3], y=max(df$Value), label = "Label"), colour = "black", vjust = 1, size = 5, nudge_y = 1) +
  annotate("segment", x=df$Date[3], xend=df$Date[3], y=0, yend=max(df$Value), linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

Look at the last two lines above: I use `nudge_y` in the call to `geom_text` to move the label up and then I use `annotate` to draw a fixed-length line.

I also made some minor edits to other parts of your code. Notably, you don't have to preface column names with `df$` if they're in your `aes()` calls and the `colour` argument of `aes` should always be an unquoted (no `"`) column name.

Comment: This looks like a great approach. Agree with notes about `aes` and `colour`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there are better options out there, but here is one approach.

Add additional margin space above the plot with `plot.margin` in your `theme`.

Add `coord_cartesian` to turn off clipping (allowing drawing outside the extent of the plot panel).

Use `annotation_custom` to add the text.

```
library(ggplot2)

date <- seq(2000, 2010, by = 1)
value <- seq(1, 11, by=1)
df <- data.frame(Date = date, Value = value) 

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, colour = Value), size = 1) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,1,1,1), "cm"), axis.line = element_line(colour = "grey", size = 0.8)) + 
  labs(y = "\n \n", x = "", colour = "") + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", face = "plain", size = 12, colour = "black")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = df$Date[c(3)], linetype="dashed", colour = "black", size=1) + 
  annotation_custom(grob = textGrob(label = "Label", hjust = .5, gp = gpar(cex = 1.2)),
                    ymin = 12, ymax = 12, xmin = df$Date[c(3)], xmax = df$Date[c(3)]) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image: ggplot with custom annotation text in margin]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go with `geom_segment`. I also made similar edits to your code as amoeba did

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, colour = "Value"), size = 1) + 
  labs(y = "\n \n", x = "", colour = "") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "grey", size = 0.8),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", 
                                  face = "plain", 
                                  size = 12, 
                                  colour = "black")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = df$Date[3],xend=df$Date[3],y=0,yend=max(value*0.97)), 
               linetype="dashed", colour = "black", size=1) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=df$Date[3], y= Inf, label = "Label"), colour = "black", vjust = 1, size = 5)+
  ylim(0,NA)
```

[image]